# when looping through the DOM how do I check if I reached the body element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, compare

I'm looping through the DOM from a link element to the closest element with class *.ui-mobile-viewport*. This can either be a **DIV** or the **BODY** element.

I need to check which element it is and am getting nowhere... this is what I'm trying:

```
var targetViewport;
```

// loop sets targetViewport as a $('div.ui-mobile-viewport') or $('body.ui-mobile-viewport')

```
if ( targetViewport === $('body') ) {
   console.log("found a body");
   }
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: Reason you are not using [closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)?

Comment: You mean check if targetViewport.closest('body').length > 0?

Comment: @frequent: or even `if ($('yourlink').closest('.ui-mobile-viewport').is('body')) { /* blah */ }`

Comment: Ok. All good answer. I like is() and closest() best. Good point with the pure Javascript solultion. Thank you all!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of doing the traversal yourself, you could try using the `.closest()` method of jQuery. So I think you could do this:

```
var x = $('thing-that-was-clicked').closest('.ui-mobile-viewport');
alert(x.is('body'));
alert(x.is('div'));
```

Now you have that `.ui-mobile-viewport` element as a jQuery object you can run any tests you want on it such as checking for `body` or `div` as show in the above code.

Answer (score 2):

you cannot compare jQuery collections... you have to actually compare their nodes, so assuming that targetViewport also holds a jQuery collection you can do

```
if ( targetViewport[0] === document.body ) {
  console.log("found a body");
}
```

should work...

EDIT: if you like the jQuery way (with an additional function call)

```
if (targetViewport.is('body')) {
  console.log("found a body");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply access the nodeName for the element.

```
if (targetViewport[0].nodeName.toUpperCase() === 'BODY') {

}
```

That way there is no need to do any CSS query for your check, invoke jQuery and it is not dependent on any library.

Comment: The original question indicates that targetViewport is already a jQuery object so the "avoid jQuery" point is neither here nor there; however, this is still a good answer. Er... assuming targetViewport is available for comparison in this manner. I didn't test.

Comment: True, which make me think this would fail but updated now to grab the element itself. I was not saying avoid jQuery but not invoke it. As this approach will not use the selector engine like is() would it would however run faster even if the code is not as pretty to look at.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(targetViewport[0] === document.body)
if(targetViewport[0].nodeName === 'BODY')
```

Comment: ... since when has one line of code with no explanation and no link to documentation been an answer?

Comment: when its self explanitory and a correct answer, nodeName is the name of the node.. do you want me to explain why 2+2 is 4 with some sweeties to represent the numerical value of 1?

Comment: [See #10](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118582/what-is-an-acceptable-answer)

Comment: "self-explanatory" in code is ALWAYS a judgment call, and the questions and answers are read by people other than the original poster. Some people actually WON'T know what the term "node" means or that they have names. Always assume at least one of these people will need or want an explanation. And some sweeties!

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the [`.is()` method](http://api.jquery.com/is/), which checks whether the an element matches a selector.

```
if (targetViewport.is('body'))
```

Comment: this only works if `targetViewport` is a jQuery wrappet set, which doens't sound like its the case

Comment: @jAndy: it will be $('div.ui-mobile-viewport') or $('body.ui-mobile-viewport'). Adding it to the question.

Comment: well then, this answer will satisfy your needs.

Comment: ... since when has one line of code with no explanation and no link to documentation been an answer?

Comment: @Matt: well, I guess in such a very simplified environment, it might be fine to just have a code-line as answer, because the question was very specific. Its no reason to downvote this, in this case, imo.